# Как правильно сравнить double и float

Tags: java, примитивы

Имеется такой код:

```
double doubleValue = 1.1D;
float floatValue = 1.1F;

Log.d("tagTest", "== -> " + (doubleValue == Double.valueOf((double) floatValue)));    
Log.d("tagTest", "== -> " + (doubleValue == floatValue));
Log.d("tagTest", "== -> " + (doubleValue == ((double)floatValue)));
```

> D/tagTest: == -> false
>
> D/tagTest: == -> false
>
> D/tagTest: == -> false

Вопрос: Есть ли возможность сравнивать два этих типа?

**UP:** Можно еще сравнить так, но в этом случае и в случае из комментария мы теряем точность.

```
Log.d("tagTest", "== -> " + ((float)doubleValue == floatValue));
```

> D/tagTest: == -> true

***Самое главное, к чему я пришел, их никак правильно не сравнишь.***

На хабре прочитал [такое](https://habr.com/ru/post/331814/):

> Статья также написана для тех из вас, у кого много данных. Если вам требуется несколько чисел тут или там, просто используйте double и не забивайте себе голову!

Comment: Например так можно "сравнивать" числа с плавающей точкой `abs(doubleValue-floatValue )<0.001` точность выбирайте сами(0.001 в примере)

Comment: Всё гениальное просто, и всё простое гениально. Метод вполне жизнеспособный..

Answer (score 0):

Сравнивайте разницу чисел с точностью float:

```
double d = 1.1;          
float f = 1.1f;
System.out.println(Math.abs(d - f) < 1e-7 * Math.abs(f));
```